# Python TypeError: 'str' object is not callable image

Tags: python

```
test_image = image.load_img('dataset/kot/cat.4003.jpg', target_size = (64, 64))
test_image = image.img_to_array('cat.4003.jpg'(64, 64))
test_image = np.expand_dims('dataset/kot/cat.4003.jpg', axis = 0)
```

Hi guys,
Could you tell me what's wrong with this code? I'm really new in this,
And i got this error as you can see above. Maybe you can see more mistakes.  I would be grateful for that.

Comment: I think this is just a typo. Should there be a comma in `'cat.4003.jpg'(64, 64)`?

Answer (score 2):

Missing comma on img_to_array parameters, between the image and the shape